# I'm not sure how to make a group selector in scss for this situation

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to learn SCSS and encountered a small obstacle (if you can call it that) with something I am trying to do.

So the code beneath is probably a non-logical, simplified example of what I am trying to achieve.:

```
.gt-button {
  // some css
  &.gt-button-alt-l {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

.gt-buttonset {
  // some css
  &.gt-button-alt-l > .gt-button {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

This will generate:

```
.gt-button.gt-button-alt-l {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.gt-buttonset.gt-button-alt-l > .gt-button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

So I am wondering how to logically get underneath CSS instead:

```
.gt-button.gt-button-alt-l, .gt-buttonset.gt-button-alt-l > .gt-button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

How would I go about getting above generated CSS? I have fiddled around in [Sassmeister.com](https://www.sassmeister.com/) but I cannot seem to get it in a way that is logical to me. I also don't really know the technical term of joining those two CSS pieces into the desired generated CSS piece.

I do have to add that I did get it to work like this:

```
.gt-button {
  &.gt-button-alt-l, .gt-buttonset .gt-button-alt-l > & {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

But that for some reason does not seem logical to me. As `.gt-buttonset` is no child or anything of the `.gt-button`. So putting it there just feels weird.

I would appreciate to know if the last code fragment actually is the way to do this or if there are other options. If there are other options I would also like to know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the outputted CSS is *that* important to you, you could leverage [the `@extend` rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) to achieve it:

**Source SCSS:**

```
.font-size-two { font-size: 2em; }

.gt-button {
  // some css
  &.gt-button-alt-l {
    @extend .font-size-two;
  }
}

.gt-buttonset {
  // some css
  &.gt-button-alt-l > .gt-button {
    @extend .font-size-two;
  }
}
```

**Output CSS:**

```css
.font-size-two, .gt-buttonset.gt-button-alt-l > .gt-button, .gt-button.gt-button-alt-l {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Obviously, the downside is that you now also have an unused `.font-size-two` class in your CSS.

That said, you may be focusing too much on the nuances of the output CSS-- as long as what you have in your SCSS is expressive, maintainable, and doesn't generate a *ton* of superfluous CSS output, I would think that to be sufficient, and not worry that every possible optimization is being made.  Remember that if you're leveraging any other build tools there will be minification and potentially other optimizations, and that CSS is, ultimately, quite fast.

Comment: I am probably focussing to much on the output yes, but its only a learning process atm. Your answer got me to think tho, for some reason it makes sense to me if I would extent ```.gt-button-alt-l``` inside of that bottom inner part. It gives exactly what I would expect whilst still leaving ```.gt-buttonset``` on his own. It also does not add a new unused class. Is that a possible solution? Or is that a bad practice? Also thx for the quick response.

Comment: @B.Dionys - I'm not certain I'm visualizing what you are describing, but my hunch is that what you are describing is a bad practice, for the following reasons-- 1) It is abstracting in a manner that makes it difficult to quickly see and understand what styles are being applied; 2) Any changes you make to the original class will be picked up to classes that extend it, which could lead to unexpected styling issues.  If you're using extending, you should limit it to cases in which you know the classes should _always_ share the originals or extend narrowly defined utility classes. Happy coding!

Comment: I think u got the gist of what I meant because it would be difficult to spot the original CSS the way I envisioned it in my comment just now, ill refrain from doing that. Thx for the explanations.